# Restlet- Send custom status code and message in Ajax response

Tags: java, rest, restlet, restlet-2.0

I have created an application in RestLet and now I want to create a custom status code message e.g. `10001 - Give Account Detail` how can I create this?

As I check there are 2 status libraries available in RestLet one is
org.restlet.resource.Status and org.restlet.data.Status.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class `org.restlet.data.Status`, as described below:

```
getResponse().setStatus(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_CONFLICT, "There is a conflict");
```

If you want to use a custom status, you can simply instantiate it and then use it:

```
Status s = new Status(10001, "Give Accound Detail");
```

In the context of exceptions / errors, you can have a look at this post:

- **Exception handling with Restlet** - https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/02/27/exception-handling-with-restlet/

That said, a good approach consists in using the status code defined by HTTP itself. You generally find what you expect.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry